# Using 2 maps in netlogo

Tags: gis, netlogo

Is it possible to use two maps in a netlogo model? If yes, how to combine or to import it to netlogo?

The first map has land use value and the second map has the land price value. So, I need these two attribute to support my model.

Below code is for importing the first map;

```
to-report read-map[m] 
let raster-map gis:load-dataset m                                         
gis:load-dataset m
gis:set-world-envelope gis:envelope-of raster-map
report raster-map

end

to read-input-maps[m]
let data-source word"data/input/maps/" m
let input-map read-map data-source
gis:apply-raster input-map map-value
ask patches
[set map-value ifelse-value (map-value <= 0 or map-value >= 0)
[map-value]
[-9999]]                                                                         
end

to read-map-attributes[m]
let data-source word "data/input/maps/"m
file-open data-source
set n-cols read-from-string remove "NCOLS"file-read-line
set n-rows read-from-string remove "NROWS" file-read-line
set xll read-from-string remove "XLLCORNER" file-read-line
set yll read-from-string remove "YLLCORNER" file-read-line
set cell-size read-from-string remove "CELLSIZE"file-read-line
file-close
resize-map

end

to resize-map
  resize-world 0 n-cols 0 n-rows
  set-patch-size 50 / cell-size

 end

  to display-map
  ifelse input-file = "turi3400m2.asc"[
  ask patches with[map-value = 1] [ set pcolor orange];Hutan sekunder orange 
  ask patches with[map-value = 2] [ set pcolor orange];Semak/belukar orange
  ask patches with[map-value = 3] [ set pcolor yellow];Permukiman yellow
  ask patches with[map-value = 4] [ set pcolor green];Kebun campuran green
  ask patches with[map-value = 5] [ set pcolor green];Sawah green
  ask patches with[map-value = 6] [ set pcolor orange];Tanah terbuka orange
  ask patches with[map-value = 7] [ set pcolor green];Tegalan/ladang green

   ]
  end

  to setup-function [m]
    read-map-attributes m
    read-input-maps m
    display-map
   end


  to setup
    ca
    setup-function 
    Input-File
```

Please help to solve this problem.

Comment: What obstacle is preventing you from using two maps...? Did you try it?

Comment: I have tried it.. but it seemed netlogo only can handle one raster map. Now, I am trying to modify the shapefile map so I can use the value of the map that I need in the model.

Comment: What does "NetLogo only can handle one raster map" even mean? How do you know? What exactly did you try?

Comment: Actually I am still studying it, but as far as I know that we can import map to netlogo that its format .asc, txt or .shp. Asc and txt format are also known as raster map. I have imported a raster map to my model. I want to import one more raster map to the model since I need some values from the map to support the model but so far I still can't do it. It seems that netlogo model can only use one raster map. But, for shp format map or shapefile we can import more than one map to the model. If it's true that netlogo only able to import 1 raster map than I hv to use the shp map to substitute it.

Comment: You _still_ haven't provided any actual evidence for saying "It seems that netlogo model can only use one raster map". What exactly makes you say so? What did you try?

Comment: I imported a raster map. So there is already a value in each patch of the raster map in Netlogo. I have been trying to import the second map. I am trying to use above code to import it. It seems netlogo can only use one raster map because if another map is added then the first patch will be covered by the 2nd. But, I conclude that way because I don't know how to import the second map or is it possible or not.So,please help to find the answer or maybe you can point out from above code which one that I can use or modify to import the 2nd map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about replacing:

```
patches-own [map-value]

gis:apply-raster input-map map-value
```

with:

```
patches-own [map-value-1 map-value-2]

ifelse m = "..."
  [ gis:apply-raster input-map map-value-1 ]
  [ gis:apply-raster input-map map-value-2 ]
```

This is the simplest possible fix I can think of. Is it adequate for your use case?